# Context-oriented encoding of WinAPI functions

Tags: windows, winapi, nlp, word-embedding

Long story short, I've got a list of WinAPI calls from a random program and I want to perform some data analysis on it (f.e. classification or sequence labeling).

Obviously, I cannot work with symbolic names, so I wondering is there any way to represent functions as a vectors based on their context (by analogy with word embedding) or there is no or quite weak dependency beetween context and purpose of function.

So, briefly speaking, *I'm looking for the algorithm (or at least for some ideas to start with) which maps WinAPI function to its vector representation, depending on function context (argument list).*

Comment: And what is your *programming* problem?

Comment: @IInspectable Ok, I'll try to state my problem clearly: _I'm looking for the algorithm (or at least for some ideas to start with) which maps WinAPI function to its vector representation, depending on function context (argument list)._

Being unpleasantly surprised by you question, I've checked stackoverflow rules ([help/on-topic]) and found that although my question does not have any source code, it generally falls into the categories "a software algorithm" and "answerable problem that is unique to software development", so, I suppose, I still in the right place to ask my question.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your interest.

Comment: *"Any ideas will be useful!"* is the precursor to an open-ended discussion. This is decidedly not the type of content Stack Overflow is trying to accumulate. Please ask a *specific* question.

Comment: @IInspectable Frankly speaking, this cavil seems riduculous to me, but in order to end this discussion, which has nothing to do with solution of the problem stated, I'll follow your advice and replace "the precursor" with brief summary of my question.

Comment: It would seem rather less ridiculous, had you taken the [tour] when it was offered to you.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a vector representation of the argument list that is suitable for classification?
You need to decide whether you want a list of argument names or argument types, but the general approach should work for both:

1. Use a symbol table that maps every argument name (or type) into a number (symbol id).
2. Turn every symbol id into a little vector that has as many entries as the symbol table has entries, and has a 1 on the position that corresponds to your symbol id and all zeros otherwise. (this is called one-hot encoding)

   3. Do this for all the arguments of a function, and concatenate the vectors into one long vector. Be sure that the first argument's vector goes first into the long vector, second argument second etc.
   4. You now have a context vector that you could use as the feature vector in a classifier.

Comment: Thank you for the response! But would it be an efficient method to encode functions? In other words, do functions serve similar tasks if they have similar argument types (names)?

Comment: That is for you to figure out.